# Should an entity access the Service Layer and execute Update/Save methods?

Tags: c#, service, model, updatemodel

My application requirements: if any property is changed by the user - like entering data into a textbox and then leaving the textbox - it must be updated immediately to the database.

I using WPF with MVVM design pattern. All my entities implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
If any property of a CUSTOMER changes I do

```
Customer.cs

customerService.UpdateCustomer(this);
```

Should an entity really update itself? Or induce its own update into the database?

I mean how else could I do an immediate upate of a property if not within the entity ?

Answer (score 0):

An entity should not update itself; another service (repository) should do that.
You can induce the repository that the entity should be updated, by subscribing to the `PropertyChanged` event of the entity.
In the eventhandler, you can make sure that your entity is updated:

```
Customer c = new Customer();

c.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => customerService.UpdateCustomer(c);
```

But, on a sidenote, I think it is a strange requirement that your entity should be changed whenever a property changes.
This means that transactions are quite useless.  I mean, you have no real 'unit of work', where all changes should be committed, or should not be persisted at all ?
Next to that, it also results in lots of roundtrips to the database.

Comment: Yes I know your concern Frederik. But they do not count for my requirements. In my application I do not want to remind/force the user to press a save button to have its changes saved. Therefore on every LostFocus of a Textbox a PropChange is fired and so the service is called. Btw. you said an entity should ot update itself... another service... thats exactly what I wrote. I just did not write c.PropertyChanged += etc... so we both came to the same conclusion.

Comment: In a former code I did this:  this.PropertyChanged += (o, e) =>
            {
                switch (e.PropertyName)
                {
                    case "Homework": _lpRepo.UpdateHomeWork(PeriodNumber, LessonDayDate, Homework); break;
                    case "Content": _lpRepo.UpdateContent(PeriodNumber, LessonDayDate, Content); break;
                }
            }; Homework or Content property can be long RTF-String which needs its time so save therefore I have 2 extra Update methods on the period...

Comment: Just imagine this scenario: my app has 8 modules in each the user can add/del objects or change properties. Now there is a save button the user should press: Now I must find out which objects got removed/added/change. The same when he wants to close the app so I can popup a last messagebox:"You have change data , do you want to save?" just like in word. But Word has just a document. I have 8 "documents" much more complicated. So my requriement is fine do you agree? ;-) btw. I use sqlite with STApplication. I do not care for roundtrips.